Which possible arrangements of a $4n \times 4n$ grid coloured with $4$ colours can we reach using Row and Column permutations?
Consider the set $S_n$ of all $4n \times 4n$ grids of squares coloured using $4$ colours (or equivalently matrices whose entries are $0,1,2,3$) such that every row and every column contains exactly $n$ squares of each colour.
Is it possible to go from one such arrangement to any other such arrangement by only permuting the rows and columns. In other words if we're given two such arrangements $A_1,A_2 \in S_n$ can we always find permutation matrices $R$ and $C$ such that
$$RA_1C=A_2$$
The result seems true for $n=1$ but I'm struggling to try and go any further.
If it isn't possible is there a way to characterise which for which subsets of $S_n$ it is possible?

Could you please add why you think it’s true for $n=1$?

@Pranay I'm thinking about it again and maybe it isn't true for $n=1$. I'm still trying to figure out for which subsets it is and isn't possible.

HINT: For $n=1$, your grids are exactly the Latin squares.
